# When try to set cookie on Jquery-ui Dialog. it does not show up, so neither work

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-ui-dialog, show

i know there are more question related to this problem, but they're not active and more than 1 year old.

I have a jquery ui dialog which works fine but i want to set a cookie so it show's up once for the user.

is t an idea to use a setcookie function? or doesn't that work fine with jquery? i am not that good with jquery at all so i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

an older question with the same problem: [Help With Setting Cookie for a JQuery UI Modal Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913218/help-with-setting-cookie-for-a-jquery-ui-modal-dialog)

this is my code:

```
$(function() {
        if ($.cookie('showDialog') == undefined || $.cookie('showDialog') == null || $.cookie('showDialog') != 'false') {

$( "#dialog" ).dialog(
{ 
show: "slow",
modal: "true",
width: 600,
show: "fold",
hide: "fade",
resizable: false,
draggable: false,
buttons: [ { id: "go", text: "Opslaan", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } } ],
open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();  }});
$(".ui-widget-overlay").css({background: "#000", opacity: 0.8});
});

$.cookie('showDialog', 'false', { expires: 1 }); // set the cookie, with expiry after 1 day
    }
});
```

I tried to set a cookie but then it failed to show up. really strange.
i thinks the code for my dialog and the cookie code are messing up eachother.

thanks

Comment: I see no code that you tried here which will set a cookie. Show your actual code.

Comment: Yeah i set a cookie as in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11843188/1379394

Comment: but that did not work so maybe i implemented it wrong. that's why i deleted it from my code.

Comment: like that. see the edit

Comment: Please confirm that you have the jquery cookie plugin in the page also. https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/ And do note that neither of the answers your provided links for were marked as answered. Just wanted to point that out so you don't depend on them too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY IT OUT HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/SkHJw/

#### First

include the jquery cookie plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/

#### Second

Create the cookie where you want it

```
$.cookie('showDialog', true);
```

#### Third

Get rid of the extra curly bracket and parenthesis in your code (this should fix your dialog box issue). I've taken them off below:

```
$(function() {

    if ($.cookie('showDialog') == undefined || $.cookie('showDialog') == null || $.cookie('showDialog') != 'false') {

        $( "#dialog" ).dialog(
        { 
        show: "slow",
        modal: "true",
        width: 600,
        show: "fold",
        hide: "fade",
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        buttons: [ { id: "go", text: "Opslaan", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } } ],
        open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();  }});
        $(".ui-widget-overlay").css({background: "#000", opacity: 0.8});

        $.cookie('showDialog', 'false', { expires: 1 }); // set the cookie, with expiry after 1 day
    }


////$.cookie('showDialog', true);  //uncomment this line to set cookie to true - this should show dialog
//alert($.cookie('showDialog')); //Uncomment this line to show the value of your cookie. It should read false and dialog would not launch;

});
```

#### Fourth

Check Your if statement

Don't forget that the above if statements means dialog should not show if cookie value is false. This should be default if cookie is not set. So set cookie if you expect dialog to show or change the if statement like below depending on your preference:

```
if ($.cookie('showDialog') == undefined || $.cookie('showDialog') == null || $.cookie('showDialog') != 'true') {
```

#### You might need these below for how to actually use the jquery.cookie plugin:

### Usage

Create session cookie:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
```

Create expiring cookie, 7 days from then:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });
```

Create expiring cookie, valid across entire site:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

Read cookie:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie'); // => "the_value"
$.cookie('not_existing'); // => undefined
```

Read all available cookies:

```
$.cookie(); // => { "the_cookie": "the_value", "...remaining": "cookies" }
```

Delete cookie:

```
// Returns true when cookie was found, false when no cookie was found...
$.removeCookie('the_cookie');

// Same path as when the cookie was written...
$.removeCookie('the_cookie', { path: '/' });
```

Note: when deleting a cookie, you must pass the exact same path, domain and secure options that were used to set the cookie, unless you're relying on the default options that is.

Find out more here: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/

Comment: Oh there's one thing. it show's me the dialog text on top of page. how can i hide that?